# Backup website with SSH to offsite location

Tags: ssh, backup, ftp, disk-space-utilization

I need to backup a website, but I am working within size constraints. I've tried the old

```
tar -cpzf backup.tar.gz *
```

but there isn't enough free space on the host to write the file. I have a few other servers that have enough space and that support SSH though.

How would I redirect the output of the tar command (using >) to another server?

If this isn't feasible, is there a better way to do this aside from just using up a ton of bandwidth by SSHing into the other server and from there using FTP over SSH to download all the files and tarball them up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [cyberciti.biz](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-tar-command-through-network-over-ssh-session/):

> tar zcvf - /wwwdata | ssh root@dumpserver.nixcraft.in "cat > /backup/wwwdata.tar.gz"

You might want to use [rsync over ssh](http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html) instead.

Comment: Yeah, best to use rsync... but cool tar trick I didn't know!

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe tar thru ssh.  Steps on Linux:   http://www.topwebhosts.org/articles/remote-backup-tar-ssh-cron.php

Answer (score -1):

Here is my backup script it taks backup of website and mysql

http://paste2.org/p/1509368

Comment: The OP doesn't have space to store tarballs locally on his server. Your script requires this.

Comment: Ahh sry must havet overlooked that